# AnimationSet performance issue

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-animation

I started working with animation in Android and want to do it correctly. So, basically, I want to implement something like this:
[image]

My code to do this:

frg_wave.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    tools:alpha="0.2"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view3"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view4"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view5"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_circle"
    />
```

and in Fragment I have

```
 private View mWave1;
private View mWave2;
private View mWave3;
private View mWave4;
private View mWave5;

private AnimatorSet setAnimation;



PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 10F);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 10F);
PropertyValuesHolder alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1F, 0.05F);

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_wave, container, false);
    mWave1 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view1);
    mWave2 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view2);
    mWave3 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view3);
    mWave4 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view4);
    mWave5 = view.findViewById(R.id.wave_view5);
    setupAnimatorSet();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setAnimation.start();
}

private void setupAnimatorSet(){
    setAnimation = new AnimatorSet();

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave1));

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave2)).after(1000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave3)).after(2000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave4)).after(3000L);

    setAnimation.play(waveAnimation(mWave5)).after(4000L);

}



private ObjectAnimator waveAnimation(View view){
    ObjectAnimator scaleAnimation =
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, pvhX, pvhY, alpha);
    scaleAnimation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(5000L);
    return scaleAnimation;
}
```

and wave_circle.xml is

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

It seems to work fine but I enable GPU rendering and see that I have not very good implementation. I very close to limit, and if I add other animation (for example rotation of view) I'll be over the limit of 16 ms. 
[image]

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?
P.S I also tried to do with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and it's not helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple scale animations burden the `RenderAnimator`, that is why you are experiencing FPS drop. You also loose some fps for the `ObjectAnimator` resolve properties of the object, instead you could try to use `ViewPropertyAnimator`.

You can improve this by animating `ImageView` `Matrix`, it has `setScale(xScale, yScale)`. Which means you have to use some `ValueAnimator` to only animate the scale factors, apply the `Matrix` [scale factors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setScale(float,%20float)) and set it to your `ImageView`s:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(scale, scale, mPivotX, mPivotY);
mTargetScalingView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

**But best performance** you will achieve, if you draw the circles on `Canvas`, which is relatively easy thing to do, and then only animate the radius of the circles, which will mimic the scaling you are trying to achieve. I guess that you want to achieve animation that tinder app has, which basically is increasing the radius of a circle and decreasing the alpha of the solid color and spawns new circle to the half of the time it takes for the color reach full transparency (yeah, this is just what I see). `Canvas` animations are great if yo want to achieve 60fps.

Be careful you don't perform any heavy iterations/operations here, otherwise you will not get 60fps.

This will cut the view hierarchy down to having only one view, instead of having for the number of waves you are trying to animate, which is another win!