# Animated background like prey app?

Tags: android, animation, background

I want to make a animated background like in the prey app:

GIF:

[image]

I tried it with a self made Canvas class and the android Timer:

**Canvas class**:

- simple class extends View
- with a android.graphics.Path (mPath)

functions:

```
public void drawCircle(float x, float y, float radius){
   mPath.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
   invalidate();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

**Activity class:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

TimerTask timertask = new TimerTask() {
   @Override
      public void run() {
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if(size > displayHeight*2 && size > displayWidth*2){
                                    canvasView.clearCanvas();
                                    size = 0;
                                    timer.cancel();
                                }
                                canvasView.clearCanvas();
                                canvasView.drawCircle(0, 0, size, Color.BLACK);
                                size+=10;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timertask, 0, 10);
```

And it worked, but very irregular and with frame drops
Please help me to find a better solution!

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` /  `ObjectAnimator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pskink gave me the tip to use the ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator

Thereby I found the solution:

**[AnimationSet performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784802/animationset-performance-issue)**

and

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/res/drawable/shape.html